# How to create a compatible heap dump with OpenJ9 via API?

Tags: java, websphere, heap-memory, dump, openj9

I try to create a heap dump with a OpenJ9 Java VM via API that is compatible with a heap dump from a Hotspot Java VM and can be use with the same analyzer tools.

I use the follow code:

```java
Class<PlatformManagedObject> clazz = (Class)Class.forName( "openj9.lang.management.OpenJ9DiagnosticsMXBean", null );
PlatformManagedObject openj9MBean = ManagementFactory.newPlatformMXBeanProxy( server, "openj9.lang.management:type=OpenJ9Diagnostics", clazz );
Method triggerDumpToFile = clazz.getMethod( "triggerDumpToFile", String.class, String.class );
triggerDumpToFile.invoke( openj9MBean, dumpAgent, file.getAbsolutePath() );
```

I try all 4 values for dumpAgent (java, snap, system and heap) but the output format is not in the *.hprof file format.

Are there other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the dumpAgent `heap` then it create a *.phd file (portable heap dump). If you want analyze it with Eclipse MAT then you need to install the `IBM Monitoring and Diagnostic Tools` plugin.

The update site ist: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/runtimes/tools/dtfj/

For Details: https://www.artificialworlds.net/blog/2016/02/23/how-to-analyse-a-phd-heap-dump-from-an-ibm-jvm/

Answer (score 1):

reference: https://github.com/eclipse-openj9/openj9/issues/6593

tldr - 2 options:

- use MAT to visualize the PHD formatted dump (https://www.eclipse.org/mat)
- use hprof agent to create the desired dump (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/samples/hprof.html)

Comment: The MAT show me the error message: "Not a HPROF heap dump (java.io.IOException)" if I try to open a phd file. What I do wrong?

Comment: How can I use hprof agent with OpenJ9? The link is related to the Hotpsot VM and not the OpenJ9.